# como usar o php dentro de um echo com html

Tags: php, html

dentro de um arquivo php gero um conteúdo html por um echo, minha duvida é como faço para usar um for php dentro desse echo.

exemplo de como estou tentando fazer;

```
    echo '<div name="estrelas-cliente">
    'for($i =1; $i <= 2 ; i++){'
      <p>teste</p>
    '}'
    </div>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você faz o echo normal da div e o echo dentro do for:

```
echo '<div name="estrelas-cliente">';
for($i =1; $i <= 2 ; i++){
  echo '<p>teste</p>';
}
echo '</div>';
```